# ui5: move selected rows from table1 to table2 in another view

Tags: sapui5

i've a requirement where i've to select (checkboxes) rows from table1 (in view1) to and paste them in table 2 (in view 2). is this possible without call any odata service in table2? please let me know the approach on how to do it. JavaScript way or does ui5 api allows doing this in a better way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer is ***No***, it isn't possible.

SAPUI5 doesn't provide any out-of-box solution/APIs for the kind of 'copy paste' mechanism on a table that you are looking for.

However, if you are *really* looking for 'dragging and dropping' UI controls, have a look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) especially the [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) sections. But beware that as you are integrating it with SAPUI5 controls, you would find unexpected results. ( You MAY not be able to do it at all )

But, if all that you are looking for is to move the data of one table to another, you can try the following,

- Assuming that you have bound an [OData model](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html) to Table1, upon completion of checkbox selection, get all the selected data from the OData model
- Use this data to then bind it to Table2 in another view. At this point I can say ***Yes***, it is possible to bind the same data to Table2 without calling another OData service

You can then fine-tune it accordingly.